# ¿Como puedo llamar a un elemento de una lista y hacer que ese elemento vaya decreciendo y se guarde en otra lista?

Tags: python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

Hola soy nuevo en python .
Si tengo mi s listas:

```
My_list=[15,2,20000]
My_list_2=[]
```

¿Como puedo llamar al primer elemento de My:list que en este caso será 15 y hacer que disminuya en 1 y que a la vez aumente en My list_2 y me quede:

```
My_list=[14,2,20000]
My_list_2=[1]
```

Comment: `My_list[0] -= 1; My_list_2,append(1)`

Comment: Muchas gracias, revise el código y si realiza lo pedido de nuevo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando quieres acceder a posiciones dentro de un arreglo, se usan `[]` y dentro, la posición a la que quieres acceder. **OJO**, si colocas un numero de posición que no existe, te tirará error.

```
My_list=[15,2,20000]
#My_list[0] => 15
#My_list[1] => 2
#My_list[2] => 20000
#My_list[3] => error(Index out of range)
```

Por lo que necesitas, es acceder a las mismas posiciones, de ambos arreglos, para eso necesitas un ciclo for en un rango especifico

```
for i in range(len(My_list)):#Recorre desde 0 hasta el tamaño del arreglo
    print(My_list[i]-=1)        #output: 14, 1, 19999
    print(My_list_2.append(1))  #output: 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu desarrollo

Comment: @AlexisRíos Denada! Recuerda que cuando haces una pregunta y te funciona, marcala como respuesta, para futuras personas que llegen a tu pregunta y sepan que fue lo que te ayudó. Feliz día!!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que requieres es que disminuya en 1 la primera lista y aumente en la segunda lista , sin embargo en el ejemplo que pusiste My_list_2 no contiene ningún elemento y no puedes aumentar en 1 un elemento nulo por lo que algo mas acertado sería:

My_list = [14,2,20000]

My_list_2 = [0,0,0]

y para aumentar y disminuir 1 :

My_list[0] -=1

My_list_2[0] +=1

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu desarrollo